# Can I get a donation as a person in Poland?

Tags: non-profit, poland

I want to start non-profit organisation, but don't meet all requirements for it. 
Is it legal to get a donations from people as a person?

Comment: Donation for personal use? What will the donation be used for?

Comment: @RonBeyer for example, payment for hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to start non-profit organisation, but don't meet all
>   requirements for it. Is it legal to get a donations from people as a
>   person?

This would be treated as a personal gift to you for tax purposes, rather than as a charitable gift, but usually it is not illegal to give or receive a gift.

If the gift were conditioned on being used in a particular way, it would be treated as held in trust under the law of most common law countries. Trusts are not as much a part of the legal tradition in Poland, so I don't know how it would be treated there.

If you solicit donations for a non-profit purpose without intending that they actually be used that way, or, at least in jurisdictions with the concept of a trust, without actually using the funds in that way, you could be prosecuted or sued for fraud or breach of fiduciary duty.